# Why does my edited WtWithQt example crash?

Tags: c++, qt, wt

I am developing an application using Qt for main logic and Wt for user interface.

However I came to a problem I couldn't solve. I've applied it to the wtwithqt example.

I've only changed "passGreet" function to call the signal asynchronously instead of directly.

<strike>Application crashes at that point.</strike> I don't really understand why.

**EDIT**: Actually it really crashes when it edits Wt object at `"HelloApplication::doGreet(const QString& qname)"`

[image]
picture: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90945130/crash.png

*Probably something to the with the origin of the action starting from Qt event loop?*

Here's the code.

```
#include "HelloApplication.h"
#include "QtObject.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

QtObject::QtObject(HelloApplication *wt, QObject *parent)
  : QObject(parent),
    wt_(wt)
{}

void QtObject::passGreet(const QString& name)
{
    //Q_EMIT greet(name);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "greet", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, name));
}

void QtObject::doGreet(const QString& name)
{
    wt_->doGreet(name);
}
```

Rest of the unchanged code is here: http://pastebin.com/fih6P2eH

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of crash you're experiencing, possibly with a backtrace as well.

Comment: Right. Here you go: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90945130/crash.png, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show here is a QThread that updates the Wt widget tree, and that did not grab the WApplication::UpdateLock. Apart from ensuring that you have exclusive access to the widget tree, the update lock also sets some thread local storage, and the missing TLS (WApplication::instance()) causes your application to crash.

The required locking mechanism can be complex - it can be easier to use WServer::post() to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found this solution http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/1/topics/5182 which I can use right away.